# Pogoplug not mounting on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: hard-drive, mac, mount, webserver, onedrive

I have attached drives on Pogoplug. I tried installing their Pogoplug drive software but it does nothing. Totally nothing. I tried emailing the company and nobody responds.

I want to mount my hard drives on my Mac whether I am connected to internet or not.

I can access the server address and Pogoplug id. How do I mount the drives on my Mac. Is there any way to contact the company and tell them to at least make working software. I bought it for 100$ in the beginning.

Is there a way to install alternate software on Pogoplug to make it work faster better and simpler?

Is there an alternate service that can extend my Mac storage easily.

Comment: The amount of sloppy programming in High Sierra is becoming legendary - I wouldn't use this OS until all the bugs have been ironed out. I would try El Capitan if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Pogoplug has shut down their services. There is no solution for people who have bought products from them.